# child comments not displaying as nested

Tags: theme-development, comments, walker

I'm having some trouble getting my comments to display as nested from other comments. My current max level of depth is set to 5 through the wordpress admin panel, but all my comments appear on the same level, whether they be replies of previous or new comments. I've searched for other solutions to this problem, but it seems very specific. Take a look to see an example: http://blog.diginomics.com/bitcoins-innate-regulation/

Here is my code under functions.php:

```
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>

<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
    <div class="comment <?php if($isByAuthor){ echo 'author';}?>" id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="comment-author vcard c-image">
            <?php echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, 80 ); ?>

        </div>

        <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
        <?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="comment-text">      
            <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
```

I believe this requires me to define some sort of walker class. Here is my current walker set to null under the wp_list_comments() $args:

```
                    <?php $args = array(
                    'walker'            => null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's problem with your css. Add this in your style.css.

```
ul.children {
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

Comment: My css is correct. Somewhere I need to alter the walker class and set $depth ++ to increment with nested comments.

Comment: You don't need to set anything anywhere. Just add this code at the bottom of your style.css file and check if it's working or not. I think it should work.

Comment: Wow, turns out it was THAT simple. Thank you for the help Robert, I appreciate it.

Comment: That's cool. I am glad you got it working now. :)